# Will these kind of cookies cause security threat?

Tags: encryption, web-application, web-browser, cookies, session-management

My PHPSESSID is encrypted it says encrypted connections only. But while viewing cookie from bowser it  shows other 2-3data like in below picture
[image]

(and similar to this picture there are few more)

and viewing other sites do not show these kind of cookies built on same framework. It is normal and safe or do i need to apply some fixes? It shows both in logged in and guest users suddenly after visiting sites.

Comment: While the facility to see what the browser thinks the cookie looks like is useful, you should be looking at what the server is telling the browser in the http response header in order to form conclusions about how the system is working. The dialog above omits a lot of relevant information. If you are a developer for the site then you should have both much greater knowledge and access to determine how it is using cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are probably [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage) cookies. They pose no harm, other than tracking your users. If you are fine with that, there is nothing you need to do.

If you want to disable analytics, just remove the Javascript from your page, and you are all good.